# Cannot create a JAX-RS web service on RAD v9.6

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, websphere-portal, rad

I try to create a JAX-RS web service on RAD, I followed this [document on IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_8.5.5/com.ibm.webservice.samptut.doc/topics/jaxrstut/jaxrs_exercise12.html), and I am getting this error:

`The wsgen tool returned an error: The command line is too long`

So which is the best way to fix this error? Thanks in advance! I am using RAD ver 9.6.

And get error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmVJs.jpg

Comment: You have to give us more information (like logs) for us to help you out. I don't use RAD but I know that wsgen is used to generate the artifacts from an existing Web Service class. I guess look for errors on your Web Service Implementation and maybe there are some malformed source in it.

Comment: Hi Alvin Reyes , thanks for comment. 
First, I create Dynamic project,rememeber I just create project demo. So I create a class default, Make webservices on this class,so finaly RAD just show pop-up error messeng like this: The wsgen tool returned an error: The command line is too long.So you can comment your email , i will sent you pictures step by step i do. Tks again !

Comment: Are you able to post the screenshot on your original post? That way everyone can contribute a solution.

Comment: Alvin  Reyes : I not enought 10 Reputation so can't upload image. :( So can you give me your email .